# electron-devtools-installer and its compatability with angular 14

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Which  are the compatible version of
`electron-devtools-installer` & `angular 14`, to enable redux in `electron.js`

Redux tab shows as blank, followed this: https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer#usage

```
 await    installExtension.default(installExtension.REDUX_DEVTOOLS);
```

It load the redux but there is no data.

Comment: any luck?  I'm getting the same problem.